# Converting and Importing Google Earth Layer with KML Styles into GeoServer (SLD Format) - Styling Discrepancy

Tags: kml, google-earth, geoserver-styling

I am facing a challenge while trying to import a layer from Google Earth into GeoServer. The styles in Google Earth are in KML format, while GeoServer requires SLD format for styling. As a result, the imported layer in GeoServer does not retain the original styles from Google Earth. I need guidance on how to successfully import the layer from Google Earth into GeoServer while preserving the styling.

I have explored options like manually recreating styles and custom scripting.
I need to understand how i can publish a layer from google-earth to the geoserver without losing style information.

Comment: Please try to limit your question to a specific question rather than a general discussion. What is wrong with the approach that you have tried?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this, I'm new here.
My question is how to publish a layer from Google Earth without losing style information. Is there a geoserver extension that can do this. I can't do it manually with many kml, kmz files. I was thinking about creating a script that can convert kml files to sdl format, but I'm not sure if this is the best practice to solve my problem.

Comment: Kml is not a good format to import into GeoServer, I suspect that you will need to write your own convertor. GeoStyler may be able to hy

Comment: You could look at MapServer instead, if the end goal is have a web service ~ https://mapserver.org/input/vector/kml.html